# How to change the path of the log4j.properties file to a specific one?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, logging, log4j

Cheers,

I tried to change the file-path of the log4j.properties from /WEB-INF/classes to /WEB-INF/lib. Is there any way to archive this?
I tried context-param to set the path but I did not archive my goal.

```
<context-param>
    <!-- specifiy <path> to a log4j.properties file to superseed shipped version -->
    <param-name>LOG4J_PROPERTIES</param-name>
    <param-value>/lib/log4j.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

These are the outputs from the tomcat7-stdout.2015-04-01.log

```
----------> Parent Classloader:
org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader@2bb57fd1
.
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.properties] using org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader@2bb57fd1 class loader.
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.properties] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
log4j: Could not find resource: [null].
[EL Info]: 2015-04-01 09:05:07.764--ServerSession(598705739)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5
[EL Info]: connection: 2015-04-01 09:05:08.246--ServerSession(598705739)--file:/C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 7.0/webapps/archive/WEB-INF/lib/ot-ads.jar_AdministrationStore_url=jdbc:sqlserver://WIN-500S3SD3IQB:1433;databaseName=ECR_user=ecr login successful
started AS_BIZADMIN API Service
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using context classloader WebappClassLoader
  context: /DynamicLogService
  delegate: false
  repositories:
```

I also tried to use a Listener:

```
<listener>
<listener-class>com.company.ecm.appsrv.logging.impl.LoggingSetup</listener-class>
</listener>
```

But doesn't seem to change anything.

LoggingSetup.java:

```
package com.company.ecm.appsrv.logging.impl;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;

public class LoggingSetup
implements ServletContextListener
{
    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce)
    {
        // Nope
    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce)
    {
        ServletContext sctx = sce.getServletContext();
        Properties props = new Properties(); 
        InputStream ins = null;

        try
        {
            ins = sctx.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/lib/log4j.properties");
            if(ins == null)
                throw new RuntimeException("Could not find log4j properties");
            props.load(ins);
            String ctxName = sctx.getContextPath().substring(1);
            props.put("contextname", ctxName);
            PropertyConfigurator.configure(props);
            Logger.getRootLogger().info("Loggin set up.");
        }
        catch(IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            sctx.log("Could not setup logging", ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            if(ins != null)
            {
                try { ins.close(); } catch(IOException ex) { /* ignored */ }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Complete web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, 
Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
"http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app>
<listener>
<listener-class>com.company.ecm.appsrv.logging.impl.LoggingSetup</listener-class>
</listener>

    <context-param>
    <!-- specifiy <path> to a log4j.properties file to superseed shipped version -->
    <param-name>LOG4J_PROPERTIES</param-name>
    <param-value>/lib/log4j.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
                com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jaxws</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jaxws</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/services</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>120</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set following context param:

```
  <context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/log4j/log4j.properties</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

Don't forget to add

```
 <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
```

in web.xml

Comment: For some reason after implementing that I got an 404 Error. My Service got deployed but its not working with your solution :|

Comment: Please post your complete web.xml file

Comment: added to the startpost.

Answer (score 1):

Issue gut fixed. I just messed up with the Java code and my supervisor was back in the office this time and helped me out. Thanks four your help vijay.